# Column not mapped hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I use JPA annotations for mapping. In my table to map, i use `@Entity` annotation, and in this table, i have a column that I do not want to map. 
Is there an annotation to declare that a column is not mapped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `@Transient`:

```
@Transient
private String abc;
```

for more informations [Annotation Type Transient](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Transient.html)